# Does not it affect the efficiency to declare a function variable as local instead of global?

Tags: c, variable-declaration

I've actually seen some results by testing it, but I want to know which way is better and why.

**Question #1:** Do local variables get declared every time when I call that function again and again? I know that it is better to declare variables in the narrowest scope possible. But I can not stop myself thinking about declaring it as a global variable and make it get declared only once, not in every function call. Or, does it get declared again in every function call? I know that the scope of a local variable is only that function. So when it leaves that function, it must forget that variable as it is going out of its scope right?

**Question #2:** When I have some function variables which need to store its previous content(e.g. timer counter variables), which way is better: to declare them as a global variable or to declare them as a static local variable? I don't need them to get their initial values whenever I call that function, I am already setting them to zero or etc whenever I need.

Comment: **Question1**: what is the problem if space for variable are stack allocated each time you call the function? **Question2**:If those variables are used in function scope only, I'd declare them static inside the function scope.

Comment: Show code and test results for it, and explain how you obtained them. Otherwise it's shooting in the dark.

Comment: I meant I have seen that both ways are working well, declaring as global or static local. But I wanted to know which one is better to go. If you meant a test result in terms of speed etc, I don't actually know how or where to do that.

Comment: Efficiency analysis may be difficult. Creating and deleting is not an efficiency issue. Local variables may appear as less efficient because they are addressed relatively to a register value (SP or BP). They require a numeric addition to get their address (contrary to globals and static locals). However, local variables are usually better register optimized and cause less cache misses. The resulting efficiency will depend on particular case, but I'd bet in favor of local variables. Not speaking about program clarity, non-pollution of global name space, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Question #1:** Do local variables get declared every time when I call that function again and again?

**A1**: **Yes**, but it's not an issue really.

Declaring a local variable means that space is made for that variable on the stack, within the stack frame of that function. Declaring a variable global means that space is made for that variable in the data section of the executable (if the variable is initialized), or the BSS section (if not).

Allocating on the stack comes at zero cost. At function entry, the stack frame is sized to make room for all local variables of the function. One more or less does not matter. Statically allocating (for a global variable) is a tad quicker, but *you only get that one variable*. This can become a huge issue at some later point, e.g. if you want to make your program multithreaded, your function re-entrant, or your algorithm recursive. It can also become a major hassle during debugging, wasting hours of unproductive time while you are hunting down that bug.

(This is the main point of it all: The performance difference is really negligible. The time you can waste on a suboptimal design riddled with globals, on the other hand, can be quite significant.)

> **Question #2:** [...] which way is better: to declare them as a global variable or to declare them as a static local variable?

**A2**: From an architectural standpoint, **avoid globals *wherever possible*.** There are a few specific cases where they make sense, but you know them when you see them. If you can make it work without globals, avoid them. (The same is true, actually, for static locals. They are better than globals as they are limited in scope, and there are cases where they make sense, but local variables should really be the "default" in your mind.)

Comment: Very good answer. And upvote for warning against static locals. In fact, functions with static locals cannot be unit-tested.

Comment: @dlask They can be unit tested, but you need to take care of setting their state properly.

Comment: @user3387223 How can you set values of static locals from outside of the function? Please note that the function can be called many times when unit tests are executed.

Comment: @Marian: See, I never bothered to actually check even that much. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Also, what is unit testing? Did you mean observing local variables in debug while they can not be observed when the program is out of its scope?

Comment: @dlask File scope static local, or inside the function static local? File scope static locals you need to include your c File under test from your test file. Function static locals I agree, to the most part, you'd need some kind of debugger solution.

Comment: @abdullahcinar: Unit testing is a technique where, for every "functional unit" in your program (like, a function), you write a "test driver", i.e. an executable, a couple of functions in an executable etc., to *test* that unit (in isolation). If I put `-1` into it, does it generate the error message as expected? If I put `0` into it, does it give `0` as return value? If I put a positive value into it, does it do the correct computations? This test driver can then be executed in an automatted environment. You run `make && make test` and immediately see if your changes broke something.

Comment: @user3387223 Function static locals are those that cause problems with unit testing.

Comment: @abdullahcinar: [Unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) on Wikipedia. Unit testing [at work](https://bitbucket.org/pdclib/pdclib/src/c73e17716f5adc26f7a4f9aff06db1c5ee35c19e/functions/string/strlen.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) in a C library implementation file. Note the `main()` function compiled in if `TEST` is defined, turning the library source file into an executable that can be used to test the library function. If `REGTEST` is defined as well, the library implementation is omitted and the test driver is linked against the system libc for comparison.

Comment: @dlask in that case, sorry, I was thinking of file scope static.

Comment: @DevSolar I understand that. I have not used such test method before, but thanks for the tip and warning. I will keep it in my mind to avoid such problems if I use it. Also, I am on your links to learn how to do a unit test, thanks for everything.

Comment: @DevSolar, "They are better than globals as they are limited in scope" what is the advantage of having limited scope ?

Comment: @fedi: A function that does not access globals, or statics, or external data, is defined in its functionality only by its direct parameters. You put a value `x` in and you get a value `y` out. Every time you put the same `x` in, you get the same `y` out. You can test this, you can understand this when scanning the code. With a static, you need to take that static's value into account to predict, or understand, how the function works, but at least you know that changing the static will only affect *this* function. Globals are a step toward the worse, with potential side-effects everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> **Global variable** - declared at the start of the program, their global scope means they can be used in any procedure or subroutine in
>   the program

It is seldom advisable to use Global variables as they are liable to cause bugs, waste memory and can be hard to follow when tracing code. If you declare a global variable it will continue to use memory whilst a program is running even if you no longer need/use it.

> **Local variable** - declared within subroutines or programming blocks, their local scope means they can only be used within the
>   subroutine or program block they were declared in

Local variables are initiated within a limited scope, this means they are declared when a function or subroutine is called, and once the function ends, the memory taken up by the variable is released. This contrasts with global variables which do not release memory.

---

**Question #1:** **YES.** Local variables get declared every time when you call that function again and again. After it leaves the function it forgots the variables that you declared in that scope. You must also remember that when some variable faced, the program will start to search for it. So when it is closer like declaring in the same scope, it will find faster and be able to continue. Also this will be more efficent while you are coding and will cause less bugs and mistakes etc.

**Question #2:** If you use the same variable with different functions, I strongly suggest you to declare them as **global** or **define**, this will lead the program to carry your "counter" with it. So it can be fastly use it when you need between the scopes you travel.
**But** after these conditions I must strongly suggest you to:

> **avoid globals *wherever possible*** (as @DevSolar said)

Comment: Hi **@DevSolar**, are you sure with your argument: "*avoid globals wherever possible.*". I am asking because you are clearly has more knowledge than me, but I can't really think a code without global variables like a "**counter**" or "**max/min**". Actually if I write my code with all little functions, your thing can be pretty appliable. **So my question:** Should we write our code with the idea of too many little functions, or should we use them when we need? How does this process effect the efficiency? Thank you.

Comment: I am not quite sure what it is you are asking here. But generally speaking, you should worry about clean design more than about "performance". That does not mean you should wilfully chose badly performing designs, just that you shouldn't twist your design around what you consider "faster". Write clean, maintainable code (avoiding globals, properly modularizing your code, writing unit tests and documentation), and once you got it *working*, you can *profile* your code and optimize it where it actually matters (which is usually not where you thought it would).

Comment: Note that I am talking about global *variables* here. They are different from global *constants* (like `MAX_COUNT` or stuff like that). Those are fine, and encouraged (over "magic numbers" right there in the code). Also, I really *meant* "wherever possible". In places where you really *need* a global variable, use it. Comment, document, be aware of its potential problems, but don't crimp your design. Maintainability usually trumps other things in the long run, and if a global makes your code *easier* to maintain, so be it.

Comment: Thank you for your time, now I have more clear explanation. Especially the last sentence get me. "**_Maintainability usually trumps other things in the long run, and if a global makes your code easier to maintain, so be it._**".

Answer (score 1):

## Q2:

It is usually more preferable to use static variables in your function. The main reason is that since all functions can access global variables, it is very hard to keep track of and debug your program.

## Q1:

Yes, local variables are created every time the function it belongs to is run, and deleted when the ends.

Suppose your program has 5 functions (that are rarely used), and each function uses 6 local variables. If you change them all to global variables, you will have all 30 variables taking up space for the entire duration of your program, instead of only have 5 variables occasionally being created and destroyed. Moreover, allocation does not really take much time.